# Always Encrypted column - LINQ query Equals not working

Tags: c#, linq, always-encrypted

I have encrypted SSN column using Always Encrypted feature in SQL server 2016. When I try to get the encrypted column in LINQ I always get error. I tried equals and contains but got the same error.

```
Query = Query.Where(t => t.SSN == InputSSN);
```

> The data types char(9) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',..are incompatible in the equal to operator.
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.

SSN,InputSSN - string 
in DB  -  SSN CHar(9) Latin1_General_BIN2

Comment: Which framework are you using for your data client?

Comment: .net Framework 4.6, Entity Framework 6. Repository pattern

Comment: have you added Column Encryption Setting=Enabled to you connection string?

Comment: Yes I have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have changed the datatype in table and it worked.

Comment: Curious what did you change the datatype from -> to?