# LINQ to SQL - Always Encrypted Column - Not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am getting this error

> The data types varchar(8000) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',..are incompatible in the equal to operator. Statement(s) could not be prepared".

This is happening when I have enabled Always Encryption in DB and now trying to retrieve data using LINQ to SQL from DB.

Has anyone successfully implemented LINQ to SQL with always encryption option?

Comment: what's the SQL query you are trying to execute?

Comment: Did you already search for this error message? I find e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56280320/always-encrypted-linq-and-where-contains or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195142/always-encrypted-column-linq-query-equals-not-working

Comment: @KlausGütter  Yeah I have gone through these link and as per there solution they are asking to change datatype of column in database.  But I just want to know is there any alternative with minimum changes or not changing database column types.

Comment: @chetan    from cust in db.cust where cust.custid=custid select cust

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

- You need to use attribute as below for the columns you want to keep
  the data encrypted on your database. The “EncryptColumn” parameter in
  the “EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn.Attribute” class will be used.

> ```
> [EncryptColumn]
> public string EmailAddress
> ```

- Next you can use "`IEncryptionProvider`" interface in `ApplicationDBContext.cs`.
- Next determin your encryption key and and create encryption provider in construtor of `ApplicationDBContext.cs`.

> ```
> private readonly IEncryptionProvider _provider; 
> public ApplicatioDbContext(){
>       Initialize.EncryptionKey = "your_encryption_key";
>       this._provider = new GenerateEncryptionProvider();
> }
> ```

- Finally, we indicate that we will use the encryption provider within
  the “OnModelCreating” method.

  ```
  modelBuilder.UseEncryption(this._provider);
  ```

You can get more explanation with examples here [Encrypt Your Database Columns with EntityFramework & .NET Core](https://emrekizildas.medium.com/encrypt-your-database-columns-with-entityframework-1f129b19bdf8)